# page doesn't stop loading - javascript

Tags: javascript

what does it mean if the twirly thing in the tab of the page wont stop spinning, ie saying its loading?

i have a php for loop and in each one of these it throws out i have a javascript onload function with a for loop looking to see if that id (from mysql) is in the javascript cookie array.
hope that makes sense. it all works fine but wont stop loading.
anyway, i've played around with break and return false which stop the loading but then doesnt give me the results i want.

can anyone point me in the right direction?
thanks

this is the javascript function that is being called by an onload in the img tag that each loop created by the php for function is throwing out.
n is the id. secondarray is the cookie data put into a readable array.

```
function cookietest(n)
{ 
for (i = 0; i < secondarray.length; i++) 
{ 
if (secondarray[i] == "ca[]="+n  ) document.getElementById(n).src = "saved.png" ;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the script you are using or the page?

Comment: Check the network tab in your developer tools for any files that might be hanging.

Comment: The twirly thing, huh? It will be kind of hard getting help if you don't post your code.

Comment: Basically, the request are not being completed. You need find which one.

Comment: SO, It seems `secondarray` is a global variable. are item added to them, during the runtime?

Comment: There's an uncomplete request, as @Starx says. Also, I suggest you that you improve your question to get better answers.

Comment: no, nothing is added to the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking length inside a loop is always a killer. And breaking out of a loop at certain point, helps you improve the performance too.

```
function cookietest(n)
{ 

    var l = secondarray.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l i++) 
    { 
        if (secondarray[i] == "ca[]="+n  ) {
          document.getElementById(n).src = "saved.png" ;
          break; //break out of loop it is no longer needed I GUESS
        }
    }

}
```

<sub>P.S: I am just answering based on the codes OP provided, the culprit could be others as well.</sub>

Comment: thanks but still loading. have tried with just a fixed number too, like 8 and still keeps loading. i feel like its something with the fact that php pumps out about 10 divs each with this img tag in it which calls the javascript, is where the problem is coming from

Comment: @Lan, Then I am afraid, the problem is somewhere else